# MySQL database: how store different size of product?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web, product

I have a project where I am creating a website for Classified Items. Users on the website will add items to sell and give specifications for it.

But the problem is: On this website, a single product can be considered as different products. For example, I can sell t-shirt with two sizes:

- size: S
- ski (size: 150cm, so a binary value)

What is the best way to design table to keep these attribute and product effectively?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a basic table with the product and then you should have the basic details like the name of the product and something that's same across, eg., type, it is a shirt etc. And you should have an attribute table that has the Product ID and the attributes. You have to refer using that product ID.

Something like this:

[image]

The SQL for the same in MySQL is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Products` (
    `Product_ID` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Product_Name` varchar NOT NULL,
    `Product_Type` varchar NOT NULL,
    `TimeStamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Product_ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Product_Attributes` (
    `Product_SKU` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Product_ID` bigint NOT NULL,
    `Product_Size` bigint NOT NULL,
    `Product_Price` bigint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Product_SKU`)
);

ALTER TABLE `Product_Attributes` ADD CONSTRAINT `Product_Attributes_FK`
FOREIGN KEY (`Product_ID`)
REFERENCES `Products`(`Product_ID`);
```

Here `Product_SKU` is the Stock Keeping Unit, which is the Real Product ID for each product - T Shirt with Size S and T Shirt with Size 150 cm. And the `Product_ID` is the product's parent ID - T Shirt.

**Products**

- T Shirt - *Prod ID - 1*
- Jeans - *Prod ID - 2*

**Product SKUs** *people can buy these*

- T Shirt (Size S) - *SKU - 1* ***Can consider like 2.1***
- T Shirt (Size 150cm) - *SKU - 2* ***Can consider like 2.2***

Hope this is sound and clear.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @Strawberry Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @Strawberry Umm... Sorry? I guess I need to give a podcast for this... But let me see if I can find a blogpost or something that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean fact / dimension- or data type wise?

You can easily store the different sizes as varchar. But I would recommend you to have a fact/dimension structure where you store all details such as sizes etc. in separate table(s)  which you can reference.